# Scatter matrix with few variables with target in Y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot variable Vs SalePrice data. I tried `pd.scatter_matrix` but I am getting number of unnecessary plot with various combinations. I look for is SalePrice in Y axis and a scatter plot for each element from the data set. Here is the code I tried.

````
data_prep_num['Sales_test_data']=data_sales_price_old
att=['Sales_test_data','YearBuilt','LotArea','MSSubClass','BsmtFinSF1','TotalBsmtSF','1stFlrSF','2ndFlrSF','GrLivArea','GarageArea']
pd.scatter_matrix(data_prep_num[att],alpha=.4,figsize=(30,30))```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pd.plotting.scatter_matrix` but only want one of the rows (i.e. the `Sales_test_data` column), you can iterate over the plotting axes, and hide the combinations you don't want.

Assuming the `SalePrice` is the very first column (index 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axes = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(data_prep_num[att], alpha=0.4, figsize=(30,30))

for i in range(np.shape(axes)[0]):
    if i != 0:
        for j in range(np.shape(axes)[1]):
            axes[i,j].set_visible(False)
```

Note: This is obviously not super efficient when you start having lots of columns though.